# How to display ng-model input value as currency in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, filter, angularjs-directive

I'm having in html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="price" >

<h2>{{ price | currency}}</h2>
```

In controller

```
$scope.price = 10;   
Which displays   **$10** in h1 if i change the value in price model input.
```

I want the text box input to be in currency ($10 in input box as value).
How to achieve this?

Comment: sorry about my previous answer, I wasn't read you question properly. Please try my demo of new answer below.

Answer (score 16):

You can try using [formatters](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController#properties_%24formatters) and [parsers](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController#properties_%24parsers) like

```
app.directive('currency', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(elem, $scope, attrs, ngModel){
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function(val){
                return '$' + val
            });
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val){
                return val.replace(/^\$/, '')
            });
        }
    }
})
```

then

```
<input type="text" ng-model="price" currency>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wNBAn/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When page loaded the solution works fine. But when i change the input it just has number. I want the input box to have currency symbol when changing.

Comment: @bleedCoder did you check the fiddle... it looks fine

Comment: When the value is removed the dollar goes away. Any idea why?

Comment: @j_walker_dev It's because the regex only replaces the first matched character. Try using `/[$,]/g`.

Answer (score -3):

For input I don't use `ng-bind` or `ng-model`, I always use `ng-value` instead.

```
<input type="text" ng-value="variable | currency:'US$ '" />
```

Comment: This works on the initial display, but doesn't reformat on edit.

Comment: Well, the question is: "How to display ng-model input value as currency", and not "How to edit the input and keep the currency".

Comment: Yes, the question is "How to display ng-model **input value** as currency".  The fact that the person is asking about input values implies that they want the formatting to occur on values typed into a text box.